# Sum of Difference between login time and logout time

Tags: mysql, oracle

Hai I am having a table with the following data i need to find the sum of login hours. Please tell me how to calculate the value. Thanks in advance

```
INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000001'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 10:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 12:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000002'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 02:55:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000003'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('10-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('10-09-2008 04:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000004'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 10:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 11:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,10
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000005'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 11:40:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000006'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('03-10-2008 08:45:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('05-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,12000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000007'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('16-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('17-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000008'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 23:50:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000009'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 10:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 12:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000010'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 14:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 14:55:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000011'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('10-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('10-09-2008 04:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000012'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 22:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 23:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,10
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000013'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 23:40:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000014'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('03-10-2008 08:45:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('05-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,12000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000015'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('16-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('17-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000016'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 23:50:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000017'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 10:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 12:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000018'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 14:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 14:55:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000019'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('10-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('10-09-2008 04:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000020'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 22:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 23:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,10
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000021'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 23:40:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000022'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('03-10-2008 08:45:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('05-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,12000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000023'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('16-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('17-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000024'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 23:50:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000025'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 10:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 12:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000026'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 14:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 14:55:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000027'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-09-2008 04:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000028'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 22:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 23:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,10
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000029'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('30-09-2008 23:40:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('01-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000030'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('03-10-2008 08:45:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('05-10-2008 07:25:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,12000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000031'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('16-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('17-09-2008 09:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000032'
    ,'USER4'
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2008 23:50:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1500
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000033'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2007 05:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,122
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000034'
    ,'USER1'
    ,TO_DATE('25-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('26-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,544
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000035'
    ,'USER2'
    ,TO_DATE('25-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('26-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,355
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000036'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('24-09-2007 05:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,100
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000037'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('25-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('26-09-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,10
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET (
    CONNECTION_ID
    ,LOGIN_ID
    ,LOGIN_DTTM
    ,LOGOUT_DTTM
    ,BYTES_CNT
    ,DAILY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,MONTHLY_BILLING_STATUS
    ,LOGIN_SESSION_BILLING_AMT
    )
VALUES (
    'CON0000000038'
    ,'USER3'
    ,TO_DATE('25-12-2007 02:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,TO_DATE('25-12-2007 06:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ,1000
    ,'N'
    ,'N'
    ,NULL
    );
```

Comment: Please refer the [ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subtract the date values of later values from former values individually, and convert them to minutes, and then hours and then days provided values exceed the maximum value for each time measurement type(`day:hour:minute` format).

Lastly, sum up all values by using `rollup` :

```
select nvl("Connection Id",'T o t a l') "Connection Id", "Time Interval(day:hour:min)" 
  from
(  
  select "Connection Id", lpad(trunc("Time Interval(min)"/(60*24)),2,'0')||':'||lpad(mod(trunc("Time Interval(min)"/60),24),2,'0')||':'||lpad(round(mod("Time Interval(min)",60)),2,'0') "Time Interval(day:hour:min)" 
    from
  (
    select t.connection_id "Connection Id", sum((t.logout_dttm - t.login_dttm)*1440) "Time Interval(min)"                                     
      from isbs_session_connection_det t
     group by rollup(t.connection_id)
     order by t.connection_id 
  ) 
);
```

In your case, i've ended up with value of `21:16:00` (`21 day 16 hours`).